# Filter duplicate records and count of occurance corrosponding to a filter condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table and group the records using key: stu_class|stu_birth|stu_major. If there are duplicate records, the record with the smallest stu_id is selected. So, I need to count the total number of records with satisfied this condition.

Example:

[image]

Here, stu_id (100,101) are duplicate records based on the key. But I want to select only the smallest stu_id record. It is stu_id , 100. Simillary, stu_id (102,104) are duplicate records. but need to select stu_id 102.

Then selected record count should be 2. How can I get this count using SQL?. I mean how I can get calculated total number of records as 2.

Comment: How are 100/101 duplicates?  The birth date is different.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by stu_class, stu_birth, stu_major order by stu_id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is available in MySQL starting with version 8.

An alternative uses a correlated subquery and might be faster, even in version 8:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.stu_id = (select min(t2.stu_id)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.stu_class = t.stu_class and t2.stu_birth = t.stu_birth and t2.stu_major = t.stu_major
                 );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(stu_class, stu_birth, stu_major, stu_id)`.

EDIT

If you just want the total records, then use aggregation:

```
select stu_class, stu_birth, stu_major, min(stu_id), count(*) as cnt
from t
group by stu_class, stu_birth, stu_major;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I get the calculated total number, please?

Comment: @Vinee-the-Pooh . . . It sounds like you might just want an aggregation query.